# Replacing 3, 240V baseboard heaters with 2, 240V cadet wall heaters. How to properly disconnect third baseboard's wiring?

Tags: electrical

The overall wattage will be the same, and I'd like to use the existing thermostat. Wiring the wall heaters seems like something I can do based on the cadet video on replacing baseboard with a wall heater, but I don't understand how to disconnect the third baseboard's wiring from both the breaker and the thermostat.

I've spent the last year learning how to do a lot of home improvement from the ground up (it started with finishing a lot of the things my husband starts but doesn't finish, but I found I enjoy it) I have no electrical experience, but know how to turn off the breaker and test for power.

We have a wood stove as the main heat and supplement with electricity and plan on moving so I don't want to invest in a mini-split so don't need those suggestions, just looking to free up floor space in a tiny house full of kids and pets. We also have a month's wait for an electrician but I can wait if this is more complicated than it seems.

Comment: The best way is to remove the extra unneeded wire completely.  The second best way is to disconnect both ends and cap with wire nuts, one wire, one nut.

Comment: That should have been one wire, one nut for each wire on the circuit.  Heaters are usually just two hots with no neutral, plus ground.

Comment: Won't you need a heater there, though?  Baseboards don't take much floor space. I would think a wall unit would take more, unless it's embedded in-wall.

Comment: @crip659, thank you for your response, that sounds like something I can do. I will try the complete removal option first, and will try and remove another wire that some previous person left, not live but not capped or labeled either.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, the wall heaters I'm looking at are very small, 12"x9", they fit between studs in the wall cavity. They are forced air, so the fan being loud is one downside but they are able to give off the same heat from a smaller unit. I could have even bought just one that was 4,000 watts (the same as the three baseboards put together) but I thought two, 2,000 watt units would give off more even heat since we have a lot of windows and a sliding glass door in the room.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you would NOT disconnect the 3rd heaters wiring from the breaker or thermostat, and there's really no reason to do so. Typically the wiring would be run inside walls and other inaccessible spaces, so removing it would require a large demolition and then reconstruction project.

Turn the breaker off. Remove the cover from the wiring compartment of the heater. You will likely find some wires emerging from the wall connected to internal red and black wires, and possibly a bare or green wire held against the metal of the heater under a screw head. Undo all those connections, making note of which wires are joined together, and remove the heater from the wall. The wires coming out of the wall may or may not be inside an electrical box, and if not you will have to provide one, either an "old work" box designed to be installed inside the wall, or a surface mount box (e.g. WireMold box). After the wiring is located in a suitable box, you would connect together the wires that were connected together inside the heater, using splicing devices such as wire nuts or Wago connectors. Single wires would simply have the ends capped off or wrapped with insulating electrical tape. Finally, a cover goes on the box.

Each of those steps has its own fussy little details that you can learn about in any number of How-To books dealing with basic residential wiring, and probably online also.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I wondered if it wouldn't be hard to remove the wires completely. I don't see any boxes inside the walls (and they left giant gaping holes behind every baseboard, so now understand where some of the drafts were coming from). Your method definitely seems the easiest, I guess I just get nervous thinking about wires in the walls and hoped to remove them completely but don't need another messy project to add to the list.